# Recommended .NET encryption library

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

After reading (yet another) [post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-wrong-level-of-abstraction/) by [Jeff Atwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) more or less concluding that us mortal developers shouldn't be getting too involved with encryption, I'm left wondering what library I should be using. The only two libraries I've found that seem legitimate are entlib's and [Bouncy Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouncy_Castle_%28cryptography%29), but they don't seem much more of an abstraction than the .NET cryptography APIs to me.

I guess what I'm wondering is if there is a "jQuery of cryptography libraries" that is simple, widely-trusted, open and well-documented.

Comment: What's wrong with `System.Security.Cryptography`?

Comment: @Thorarin - That's what I've always just done, but I think the basic reason someone would argue not to use it is because there are so many options in that API that unless you understand everything, you'll end up doing something wrong.

Comment: The other one he mentions in the artcile is Keyczar

Comment: @ChrisW that one has Java, Python, and C++ implementations http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/

Comment: The question merits different answers for different use-cases -- are you transferring data to another person, or are you just needing to conceal it while you're not using it.

Comment: also for .net http://jbtule.github.io/keyczar-dotnet/

Comment: To answer @Thorarin's question, belatedly: `System.Security.Cryptography` isn't very portable.  The xplat cryptography story in .NET kinda sucks, IMO.

Comment: You can also consider the following Data Encryption Library for NET http://www.thedownloadplanet.com/reviews/review-data-encryption-library-for-net/ which helps you encrypt your sensitive file or data with just a few lines of code. It supports encryption and decryption of files and streams. Supports XTS-AES, AES, 3DES and Twofish in CBC mode, password-based protection and PBKDF2 key derivation

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**edit:** Here is a comprehensive list of popular crypto libraries from https://github.com/quozd/awesome-dotnet/blob/master/README.md#cryptography:

- [BouncyCastle](https://bouncycastle.org/) - Together with the .Net System.Security.Cryptography, the reference implementation for cryptographic algorithms on the CLR.
- [HashLib](http://hashlib.codeplex.com/) - HashLib is a collection of nearly all hash algorithms you've ever seen, it supports almost everything and is very easy to use
- [libsodium-net](https://github.com/adamcaudill/libsodium-net) - libsodium for .NET - A secure cryptographic library
- [Pkcs11Interop](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop) - Managed .NET wrapper for unmanaged PKCS#11 libraries that provide access to the cryptographic hardware
- [StreamCryptor](https://github.com/bitbeans/StreamCryptor) - Stream encryption & decryption with libsodium and protobuf
- [SecurityDriven.Inferno](https://github.com/sdrapkin/SecurityDriven.Inferno) - .NET crypto library. Professionally audited.

Original answer follows.

---

The Bouncy Castle library is indeed a well respected, and mature encryption library, but what's wrong with using many of the fantastic encryption functions that are built right into the .NET framework?

[System.Security.Cryptography Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx)

In my experience, these implementations are rock-solid, provide numerous options (for example: you've usually got a [Crypto API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_API), [CNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography_API:_Next_Generation) and Managed implementations of each algorithm to choose from) , and you're not going to "get it wrong", since you're only *using* the implementation.  If you're slightly worried that you might *use* them incorrectly, you can always follow [MSDN's own example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx).

Comment: I think the article (and their predecessors) I linked to gives compelling enough reasons as to why the majority of us developers should probably not get too carried away using that namespace. So I guess that's all to say I'm just going off what sounds like good advice.
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001275.html

Comment: You link to an example rijndael implementation, but that puts a decision on me to decide between all the different algorithms. I would prefer an abstraction that gave me methods like EncryptStringForBrowser() (an example given by Jeff) so that an expert can decide to use rijndael or aes under the hood.

Comment: @jayrdub - I see what you're saying about abstraction, but I don't think a complete full layer of extra code (as per a 3rd party lib like BC) is necessary.  You don't want to implement it yourself for good reason, and you don't want to "misuse" the implementation and weaken security.  All good things, but I think this can easily be achieved with the framework's built-in classes and the example code on MSDN.  The example there gives a "encryptStringToBytes" style function that makes it a "no-brainer" to use for strings without weakening security.

Comment: (continued).. As for the onus being on yourself to decide which algorithm to choose, well, Rijndael is the Advanced Encryption Standard and is pretty solid, and choosing between the CryptoAPI/CNG/Managed implementations should be largely a matter of speed, performance, availability of the CNG libs etc. rather than security since they are all the same algorithm.  I do agree with you regarding a certain level of abstraction to prevent us mere mortals from screwing it up, but at the same time, *too much* abstraction (using something without knowing *at all* what it's doing) can be a bad thing!

Comment: BouncyCastle doesn't even have the documentation, I don't know how to start.

Comment: Simple c# ras cryptography library https://github.com/maythamfahmi/CryptoNet

Answer (score 9):

You have completely misunderstood the maxim "do not implement encryption routines yourself". What this means is: do not roll your own RSA/DSA/whatever encryption algorithm. It doesn't mean that you shouldn't use one written by someone who knows what they are doing. In fact, if anything, adding more layers between you and the trusted algorithm is going to hurt you, and not the reverse.

Comment: It also means "don't make up your own algorithm".  The approach of "I can't see how I'd break it so I can't see how anybody else would" does not give you security.

Comment: I don't disagree, I'm just trying to get a grasp on whether or not there is some awesome library out there that I've missed out on because of the way Jeff discusses trying to avoid using .NET's API in favor of "a proven, domain-expert-tested set of code that thousands if not millions of developers already rely on". I'm getting the feeling there isn't (besides maybe the two I mentioned).

Answer (score 6):

[Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) seems to be pretty widely respected

Answer (score 1):

EntLib Cryptography block works well for most of encryption/hashing needs.